# AppCompat v22.1.0 not theming all xml widgets correctly for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-appcompat

When using xml based layouts using AppCompat 22.1.0 not all supported widgets are tinted or material themed for my Fragments using Android 4.4.

I see this behavior with the following widgets (others not tested):

- RadioButton (No tint color)
- CheckBox (No tint color)
- Spinner (Device default theme is applied)
- EditText (Device default theme is applied)
- RatingBar (Device default theme is applied)
- Button (Device default theme is applied)

It used to work in AppCompat v22.0.0.

**Screenshot (left 4.4, right 5.0):**

[image: Example screenshot]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton test"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="CheckBox test"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/someStrings"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Indeed! Quick response from Google!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is currently reported as bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169760

A temporary workaround is to use the Fragment parent Activity LayoutInflater: `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` instead of the supplied LayoutInflater in the onCreateView method.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

*Note: Another solution is to use the special AppCompat widgets in your xml layout:*

- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner

*But this would basically mean you need to replace every single widget with the AppCompat one.*

Comment: Ouch. Nice to be still on v22.

Comment: @Rolf can you mark this as correct if you figured it out?

Comment: I see the same effect as in the screenshots above for versions prior to 5.x even with AppCompat 23.0.1. The workaround makes no difference.

In my case I have an AppCompatActivity which contains a ListFragment defined in xml. The ListFragment uses the default list layout. Its highlight color is holo blue rather than my theme's colorAccent. Another list fragment contains a CheckedTextView whose check boxes do not honor the theme's accent color.

Comment: Interestingly, I get properly colored checkboxes in the list items of a fragment which *has* a list view, but is not a ListFragment .

Comment: Strange I use the ListFragment too (without xml as its not needed for the ListFragment) and it works as expected. I should mention that appcompat has no support for Material themed list selectors. So you should fix those yourself: http://motzcod.es/post/108837945597/fixing-activatedbackgroundindicator-in-appcompat

Answer (score 2):

You can force the theme applied to views, only need to add these lines on the parent view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:context="com.example.yourActivityThatHasATheme"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then all views inside the linear layout take the accent color declared to the respective activity in the manifest (Via theme).