# android AppCompat v22.1.0 button styling

Tags: android, button, android-support-library, android-styles

Problem: cant set style to my buttons correctly

source is devilishly simple:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#00FFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0030FF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#800080</item>
</style>
```

layout (applied to AppCompatActivity):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

manifest:

```
 <application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Problem 1 is: colorControlNormal doesn't affect Button (but affects CheckBox). How can I apply any color to all buttons?

Problem 2 is: android:textColorPrimary attribute sets color for Button text, but attribute android:textColor overlaps it, setting color both to TextView and Button texts. How can i set them separately?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806343/appcompat-v22-1-0-not-theming-all-xml-widgets-correctly-for-fragments

Comment: Yep, and this is not the case, nothing to do with fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set default button color by adding this line to Theme.

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/your_color</item>
```

It works on both Pre-Lollipop and Lollipop.